# Force higher-specificity prefix in all MUI/material styles

Tags: material-ui, emotion

I have an odd mix of styling libraries, particularly tailwind, and tailwind's CSS Reset is stepping over some of MUI's setting (specifically, making buttons have `background:transparent`).

I can't control those other style libraries; they're injected as microcomponents come in and out of the application.

Is it possible to force MUI to make all styles have a prefix, e.g. "#root", so MUI always wins the specificity fights?